# Переносимость *_s функций (_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)

Tags: c++, c++14, кроссплатформенность, c++17

При попытках скомпилировать код из серии

```
FILE* file = fopen(filename.c_str(), "w");
...
if (!file)
    std::cout << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
...
int fd  = fileno(file);
```

компилятор (`visual studio 2017`) выдает мне ошибки:

```
error C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
error C4996: 'strerror': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strerror_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
error C4996: 'fileno': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _fileno. See online help for details.
```

Что-то подобное он выдавал и на использование `sprintf`, но там вылечилось заменой на `snprintf`.

Смысл ошибок понятен, выключать их не хочется, так как они довольно полезные. Но слышал я, что предлагаемые компилятором замены не являются переносимыми функциями. Насколько это соответствует действительности (`c++14`, `c++17`)? Если они не переносимы, то какие есть альтернативы исправления кода так, чтобы ошибки исчезли (без учета отключения или подавления данных предупреждений), но с сохранением переносимости?

Answer (score 1):

Функции *_s являются частью стандарта `c11`, а в `c++`, судя по cppreference, они не определены.

`fopen` плох исключительно тем, что не умеет обрабатывать нулевые указатели.

`strerror` не threadsafe, если у вас несколько потоков, будут проблемы.

`fileno` deprecated только в windows. Более того, posix не определяет `_fileno`.

Ну и раз вы говорите про c++, вопрос, зачем вам понадобился c-style io? `fstream` стандартизирован и достаточно хорош для подавляющего большинства задач.

Comment: только `*_s` функции часть не обязательной части стандарта, а его опционального расширения, пролобированного понятно кем... и на сколько я знаю, пока ни одна nix'овая libc не реализует это расширение...  ИМХО большинство этих функций контрпродуктивны, а те что действительно полезны, как `strerror`, имеют POSIX аналоги с суффиксом `*_r`.